# Modify Footer in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have tried searching for the answer to this, but none of the solutions seem to show how to modify the footer.  I see this in the view for the theme:

```
    <div id="footer-sig" class="group">
        @Zone(Model.Footer)
    </div>
```

How do I modify Model.Footer?  I have the release version that I installed from the Web Installer, and it doesn't seem to have controllers or models in it, just views.  How can I modify the footer?

For instance, I just want to put a "|" in between the dashboard and other links.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, it's probably worth reading some background on [customising Orchard themes](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-the-default-theme).

This depends a lot on what it is you want to change about `Model.Footer`.  Assuming you're using the **TheThemeMachine** theme, the code snippet that you've posted is contained in `Layout.cshtml`.  If you look further up the source, you'll see the snippet:

```
WorkContext.Layout.Footer.Add(New.BadgeOfHonor(), "5"); // Powered by Orchard
WorkContext.Layout.Footer.Add(New.User(), "10"); // Login and dashboard links
```

This is telling Orchard to spin up two new shapes as part of the footer (`BadgeOfHonor` and `User`).

The `BadgeOfHonor` shape simply renders the view which is bundled into `TheTimeMachine` theme so can be easily changed.

The `User` shape has a default view in the core and renders the 'Welcome XXX / Sign in' element of the footer.  This can be overridden by your theme in the usual Orchard way.

From your comment, it sounds like you want to change the footer from `TheThemeMachine`, so that instead of saying:

```
Powered by Orchard © The Theme Machine 2010. Welcome, admin! Sign Out Dashboard
```

It says:

```
Powered by Orchard © The Theme Machine 2010. Welcome, admin! Sign Out | Dashboard
```

You can override views in Orchard by creating the appropriate view within your Theme.  So, to change the way that the `User` shape is rendered, you just need to add the view to your theme and modify it.  The easiest way to do that is to go and find the existing view and copy it into your theme, which will give you something to work from.  In this instance, the file **src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\Views\User.cshtml** would need to be copied into the folder **src\Orchard.Web\Themes\TheThemeMachine\Views\User.cshtml** (assuming you're modifying TheThemeMachine).  Then you would just need to change this code:

```
    <span class="user-actions">
        @Html.ActionLink(T("Sign Out").ToString(), "LogOff", new { Controller = "Account", Area = "Orchard.Users", ReturnUrl = Context.Request.RawUrl }, new { rel = "nofollow" })
        @if (AuthorizedFor(Orchard.Security.StandardPermissions.AccessAdminPanel)) {
            @Html.ActionLink(T("Dashboard").ToString(), "Index", new {Area = "Dashboard", Controller = "Admin"})
        }
    </span>
```

into something like this:

```
    <span class="user-actions">
        @Html.ActionLink(T("Sign Out").ToString(), "LogOff", new { Controller = "Account", Area = "Orchard.Users", ReturnUrl = Context.Request.RawUrl }, new { rel = "nofollow" })
        |
        @if (AuthorizedFor(Orchard.Security.StandardPermissions.AccessAdminPanel)) {
            @Html.ActionLink(T("Dashboard").ToString(), "Index", new {Area = "Dashboard", Controller = "Admin"})
        }
    </span>
```

Generally, It's a good idea to work on your own copy of a Theme, rather than directly modifying the ones that come with the distribution as this will make it easier for you to take updates when they come.  It's also worth looking into how ShapeTracing module, which allows you to identify which shapes you need to override to change different elements on your site.  The documentation on the [Orchard.Net](http://docs.orchardproject.net/) pages do contain some useful information (although it can get a bit out of date because the development is still moving quite quickly), so it's worth a read.

Comment: How can it be overidden?  I am new to Orchard.  For instance, I just want to put a "|" in between the dashboard and other links.  Thank you.

Comment: @user1477388: I've added a bit more information into the answer.  http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-new-theme and http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes are both well worth a read for some background.

Comment: I was wondering also, by adding the User.cshtml file to the Views folder, that effectively overrides a User.cshtml file that would be otherwise generated (from the core)?

Comment: @user1477388: Correct, It will essentially use the most specific view for a given shape.  So, it'll try your theme first if it doesn't find a match, it'll check the active modules (I'm not sure how it decides which order to search them), if it still doesn't find a match, it'll look in the core.  So if you want to replace an existing shape/view you can usually copy the source that is currently being used (use shape tracing to identify it) + then just change the bits your want.

Comment: Excellent.  One other thing I was wondering when looking at the Layout.cshtml file, I notice it has @Zone(Model.Navigation) but no reference to WorkContext.Layout.Navigation.Add(New.Navigation()) or anything like the header and footer have.  How does the Model get added to the view?  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @user1477388: Content is typically mapped to zones automatically, through the use of widgets.  Both of these are relevant: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-widgets and http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Anatomy-of-a-theme.  If you're just getting started, you may also want to at least read through something like http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1 to get a feel for what can be done + how (although it's a little out of date it's still a good resource).

Comment: I have read those, but I still don't know how to find navigation.  I looked in /core/shapes/views/menu.chstml and there is a comment that says, "// Model is Model.Menu from the layout (Layout.Menu)" but I don't know where the layout.menu is.

Comment: @user1477388: Not sure I really understand what you're asking, you might want to reformulate it and ask it as another question.  The Menu stuff has been modified in 1.5, superficially, it appears to be wrapped in a widget now, so that multiple menus are supported.  The Models are in 'Orchard.Core.Navigation.Models' (MenuPart etc), and the handlers / services are in the same Navigation section of the Orchard.Core project.

Comment: I will probably ask in another question.  But, to your last response, I don't have any Models folder in Orchard.Core.Navigation.  I am using the version installed by the Application Installer.  I have been wondering this for a while now, maybe you will know why I don't have these files in my version.

Comment: @user1477388: I guess the assumption is that you don't need them (they're already compiled into the Orchard.Core.dll) so it saves space and makes it more approachable to just bundle the views.  Downloading 'as zip' from orchardproject.net also seems to miss off the bulk of the non-view code.  If you download 'the source', however you get the logic for the models etc which might make it easier for you to get to grips with what's going on, or you can go the whole hog and take out a source code enlistment http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-source-enlistment

Comment: That sheds some light on it.  Is there anyway to edit these files otherwise, can they be overwritten similar to the view?

Comment: @user1477388: I'm not sure.  I went the enlistment route so that I have direct access to the source code when I'm trying to figure out how things are working.

Comment: Thanks, I may consider that.  You were a great help.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way out is to explore your the website files and find ~\Themes[ThemeNameOverHere]\Views\BadgeOfHonor.cshtml
Mine has this has it's content which you can easily edit:
    @T("Powered by Orchard", "http://www.orchardproject.net") @T("© The Theme Machine 2010.")

Note: Am using Orchard 1.9.1 Version.
Hope this is useful.